# Change "created date" and "created by" values for my default publishing site's welcome page, after a backup/restore

Tags: development, publishing-site, backup, restore, site-settings

I have developed an enterprise wiki site collection inside my staging server , then I backup , restore the enterprise wiki inside my live server.

But currently the created data for my welcome page is equal to the date I have created it inside the staging server and not the date i have restore it inside the live server . and also the created by is “System Account ” as shown below.

[image]

So my question if there is a way to manually modify the "created" & and "Created by" to a custom values only for the welcome page ?

Thanks

**EDIT**

i tried the following code after i added , `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()` :-

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
            InitializeControl();

            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList list = web.Lists["Pages"];
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                foreach (SPListItem items in list.Items)
                {
                    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                    {
                        items["Author"] = "Test Name";
                        items["Created"] = "01/08/2014 01:44 PM";
                        items.Update();
                    });

                }
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                    {
                list.Update();
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                    });

            }
        }
```

but this will raise the following error when i try to add the web part inside the page:-

> Invalid data has been used to update the list item.The field you are
>   trying to update may be read only

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by code behind :

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.URL))
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            SPList list = web.Lists["ListName"];
            web.AllowUnSafeUpdates = true;
            foreach (SPListItem items in list.Items)
            {
                items["Author"] = value;
                items["Created"] = value;
                items.SystemUpdate();
            }
            web.AllowUnSafeUpdates = false;
        }
```

Comment: can you explain your point in more details, where exactly i need to do so ? using the SharePoint designer ?

Comment: @Hardit Kothari thanks for the edit, but your code will update the all the pages not just the welcome page is this right ?

Comment: right. but if you require a particular item to be updated you can even modify the code using itemID and change the values.

Comment: as i did not work on such a task before let say the URL for the welcome page is "http://sps01/kb/ServiceKB/Pages/Welcome.aspx" , so how i can define this inside your code ?

Comment: you can try creating a visual web part using Visual Studio and deploy,add it on the page you want.

Comment: so is there a more straight forward approach ? what is i remove the web part will the values changed back to the old values?

Comment: easiest way you can use Client Obj Model and create a c# class file and update the list items. but creating visual web part would give you more control and on removing the web part the values won't change.

Comment: ok i got your point so i will try your approach , but what exactly i should include for the values ? for example for the "Created" column how i will be specifying the date & also for the author i can just add the user name as "John G" ?

Comment: for Created it must be data time format value like "10/09/2014 8:27 AM" or else in code you can select System.CurrentDateTime and for CreatedBy it should be the domain account UserName i.e:displayname

Comment: but how i can specify to work only on specific page (the welcome page ) ?

Comment: its the web part you will add on that particular page. so only that page will have reference to set the list updates. you can define you list action on a custom button click or on page load, depends on you

Comment: aha ok i got ur point i will try this a let u know. thanks again

Comment: i added the web-part to the page but i got the following error "unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's Execute method in the partial trust app domain"

Comment: create a visual web part(farm solution)

Comment: ok thanks . now i get the following error "Invalid data has been used to update the list item.The field you are trying to update may be read only" , when i tried to add the web part to the page. seems certain feilds are not editable ?

Comment: Try adding the code in SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedProviledges delegate and also try working around items.update() and list.Update()

Comment: can you check my edit after using SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedProviledges

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the code in SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedProviledges delegate and also try working around items.update() and list.Update()

Comment: currently i have the code inside " protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)", so should i move the code to another method?

Comment: Better you can use button click event .so u can control the update

Comment: but even if i use a button click what will this change ?

Comment: Try using the same then np

Comment: i got confused , which approach i should try ?

Comment: can you check my edit?

Comment: which edit, din't got you?

Comment: the edit to my original question, after i tried your apprach .

Comment: try my edited code. listitem.SystemUpdate() and don't use list.Update()

Comment: but your edited code does not contain listitem.SystemUpdate() ? should i add it ?